# Не переведен текст тревога>должен быть закрыт

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Почему то не переведен текст в тревоге -> вопрос должен быть закрыт
сейчас выглядит вот так :

> This question is completely unclear, incomplete, overly-broad, primarily opinion-based or is not about Stack Overflow на русском as described in the help center, and it is unlikely to be fixed via editing.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, периодически слетают строки в тревогах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В интерфейсе стала использоваться новая строка, которая уже была переведена, но не подтверждена на [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/61992668?key=33713dacb0616e353c5dd6d3e603d321).

Скорректировал, подтвердил, будет доступно со следующим обновлением базы.

> This question is completely unclear, incomplete, overly-broad, primarily opinion-based or is not about $Topic$ as described in the help center, and it is unlikely to be fixed via editing.
>
> Данный вопрос является совсем непонятным, неполным, слишком общим, основанным на личном мнении или не относится к теме $Topic$ как описано в Справке и вряд ли может быть улучшен правками.